# OAuth2.0 integration via Google in a React+Spring application

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am developing a web application using React and Spring, and I need help with setting up authorization through OAuth2.0 using Google. In my React code, I am using @react-oauth/google library and after successful authorization I am getting user credentials back from Google.

Right now I'm using authorization via email + password, but now I want to add the ability to authorize via OAuth2.

Questions:

1. What should I do after getting the data from Google on the front end?
2. What and how do I need to change in my Spring application to allow authorization via OAuth2.0?

Into **code in React** to retrieve data from Google:

```
import { GoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';
import { jwtDecode } from 'jwt-decode';
import React from 'react';
const OAuthButtons = () => {
  const handleSuccess = (credentialResponse) => {
    const decodedToken = jwtDecode(credentialResponse.credential);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <GoogleLogin
        onSuccess={handleSuccess}
        onError={() => {
          console.log('Login Failed');
        }}
        useOneTap
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default OAuthButtons;
```

My **restController** in Spring for user authorization:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/auth")
public class AuthenticationRestController {

    private final UserFacade userFacade;

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    public AuthenticationRestController(UserFacade userFacade, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.userFacade = userFacade;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }

    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registration(@RequestBody UserRequestDto userRequestDto) {
        try {
            UserResponseDto user = userFacade.createUser(userRequestDto);

            if (user != null) {
                authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getId(), userRequestDto.getPassword()));
                String token = jwtTokenProvider.createToken(user.getId(), user.getRole());
                return ResponseEntity.ok(new UserWithJwtResponseDto(token, user));
            } else {
                throw new EntityExistException("");
            }
        } catch (EntityExistException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody UserRequestDto req) {
        try {
            UserResponseDto user = userFacade.findUserByEmail(req.getEmail());
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getId(), req.getPassword()));


            String token = jwtTokenProvider.createToken(user.getId(), user.getRole());

            return ResponseEntity.ok(new UserWithJwtResponseDto(token, user));
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username or password");
        }
    }
}
```

My **SecurityConfig** on the server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    private static final String ADMIN_ENDPOINT = "/api/v1/admin/**";
    private static final String LOGIN_ENDPOINT = "/api/v1/auth/**";
    private static final String USER_ENDPOINT = "/api/v1/user/**";
    private static final String TEACHER_REGISTRATION_ENDPOINT = "/api/v1/teacher/registrationTeacher";
    private static final String TEACHER_ENDPOINT = "/api/v1/teacher/**";
    private static final String COURSES_FOR_NOT_AUTH_ENDPOINT = "/api/v1/course/findAll";
    private static final String ERROR = "/error";

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                .and()
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(LOGIN_ENDPOINT).permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(ERROR).permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(COURSES_FOR_NOT_AUTH_ENDPOINT).permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(ADMIN_ENDPOINT).hasRole(" developers:write")
                    .antMatchers(USER_ENDPOINT).hasRole("developers:read")
                    .antMatchers(TEACHER_REGISTRATION_ENDPOINT).hasRole("developers:read")
                    .antMatchers(TEACHER_ENDPOINT).hasRole("developers:educate")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider))
                .and()
                .httpBasic();;

    }
}
```

My **UserDetails** imlementation:

```
@Service
public class JwtUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public JwtUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findById(username).orElse(null);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User with username: " + username + " not found");
        }

        JwtUser jwtUser = InnerConverter.convertUserToJwtUser(user);
        if (!jwtUser.isEnabled()) {
            throw new DisabledException("User account is disabled");
        }
        return jwtUser;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have bad news:

- `@react-oauth/google` makes your Javascript frontend an OAuth2 "public" client and [this is now discouraged](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390). You should use only OAuth2 "confidential" clients, which run on servers you trust
- the audience of access tokens delivered by Google is Google. Understand that you most probably can't easily / efficiently use these access tokens to authorize requests to your own resource servers. You'll have to set up an authorization server of your own with "Login with Google" feature.

Where to go from there:

- Choose and configure an authorization server. Most OIDC offers include "Login with ...". You might consider:

  - standalone solutions like Keycloak
  - cloud offers like Auth0, Okta, Amazon Cognito, and many more
  - "do it yourself" with `spring_authorization_server` framework (probably not a good idea unless you have an advanced knowledge of OAuth2 and OpenID standards)
- choose a **B**ackend **F**or **F**rontend that you can configure with authorization_code flow and something to bridge between sessions (to authorize requests from the SPA) and access tokens (to authorize requests to resource servers). `spring-cloud-gateway` can be easily configured with `oauth2Login()` (using `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`) and the `TokenRelay` filter.
- replace token security with session + CSRF security in your react app.

I wrote [a tutorial for using `spring-cloud-gateway` as BFF](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff). It is written for Angular, but porting it to React is trivial.